# How to delete in a class an object created from another class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm learning python and tkinter, and I try to delete an object from class A in class B, but nothing happens, no error message neither when I click the butB. Thanks for any help

```
from tkinter import *
class FaceDom(object):
    def __init__(self, can):
        self.can =can
        self.can.create_line(10, 10, 90, 90, fill ='red',width=5)   
class Projet(Frame):
    def __init__(self, larg, haut):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.larg, self.haut = larg, haut
        self.can = Canvas(self, bg='dark green', width =larg, height =haut)
        self.can.pack()
        bList = [("ligne", self.butA),("Delete",self.butB)]
        for b in bList:
            Button(self, text =b[0], command =b[1]).pack()
        self.pack()
    def butA(self):     
        self.x=FaceDom(self.can)
        print(self.x)
    def butB(self):
        self.can.delete(FaceDom.x)      
Projet(100, 100).mainloop()
```

Comment: `create_line` gives ID which you have to use do delete line from canvas.

Comment: What effect do you want the deletion to have on the screen if any?

Comment: when I run it and press button delete then I see error. Did  you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_line` gives ID which you have to keep

```
self.id = self.can.create_line(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='red', width=5)
```

and use it to delete line from canvas.

```
def butB(self):
    self.can.delete(self.x.id)
```

You use this ID also to move line or change its configuration (color, etc.)

---

```
from tkinter import *

class FaceDom(object):
    def __init__(self, can):
        self.can = can
        self.id = self.can.create_line(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='red', width=5)

class Projet(Frame):

    def __init__(self, larg, haut):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.larg, self.haut = larg, haut
        self.can = Canvas(self, bg='dark green', width =larg, height =haut)
        self.can.pack()
        bList = [("ligne", self.butA),("Delete",self.butB)]
        for b in bList:
            Button(self, text =b[0], command =b[1]).pack()
        self.pack()

    def butA(self):     
        self.x = FaceDom(self.can)
        print(self.x)

    def butB(self):
        self.can.delete(self.x.id)      

Projet(100, 100).mainloop()
```